# making a joint (Distance,Revolute..) with Box2dweb and CreateJS

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, box2dweb

I found this cool tutorial about using Box2dweb in CreateJS http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=176
I m trying to make any joint but no luck, please help.